# How to exit from inotifywait

Tags: shell, inotifywait

I want to monitor a given directory until a certain condition arises.

```
ARCHIVE_PATH=$(inotifywait -m -r -q -e close_write -e moved_to --format '%w%f' /test | while read FILE; do
  # ... Code ...
  if [ $CONDITION ]; then
    echo "$VALUE"
    break
  fi
done)
```

Now, no matter whether I use `break` or `exit 0`, the while loop will continue. What is the best way of exiting the loop and passing the output to the variable, then?

**EDIT**:

Replacing `break` with `kill -2 $$` seems to only trigger a continue.
And even worse - there are times, when break works fine - but rarely.

Comment: I probably need to fetch the PID (for killing later) of the `inotifywait`, but have no idea, how.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `kill -2 -$$` or `kill -SIGINT -$$`

The minus sign in  `-$$` sends the signal to all the processes in the group. The `$$` is the current process. So `-$$` should mean: send this signal to all the processes in the group of the current process.

This man page explains more: http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill

The answer was inspired from: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=186989

Answer (score 0):

I now do this by signalling:

```
trap "exit 0" 10

ARCHIVE_PATH=$(inotifywait -m -r -q -e close_write -e moved_to --format '%w%f' /test | while read FILE; do
  # ... Code ...
  if [ $CONDITION ]; then
    echo "$VALUE"
    kill 10 $$
  fi
done)
```

Seems like the shell is not allowing `SIGINT` to be sent from a subshell or so, thus I had to send another signal (`SIGUSR1`) and trap it.